# Gulp: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir-vue-2'

Tags: laravel, npm, gulp, node-modules

I get this error when I try to use gulp in my Laravel project. I tried deleting node_modules and running `npm install`, but no lock.

```
λ gulp
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'laravel-elixir-vue-2'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\ibpc\gulpfile.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

I also tried to add it to package.json.

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-9",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you don't have `laravel-elixir-vue-2` in your `package.json` file.

Try to install package with the next command:

`npm install laravel-elixir-vue-2 --save-dev`

Or add in your `package.json` this line:

`"laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.3.0"`

Comment: I did try to add the line in package.json before, but that didn't help.

Comment: `npm install laravel-elixir-vue-2 --save-dev` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I've got same problem.
I tried to run this command

```
npm install laravel-elixir-webpack-official
```

And it fixed...